# Merge data.frames for grouped boxplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data frames z (1 million observations) and b (500k observations).

```
 z= Tracer time treatment
        15 0 S
        20 0 S
        25 0 X
        04 0 X
        55 15 S
        16 15 S
        15 15 X
        20 15 X

  b= Tracer time treatment
            2 0 S
            35 0 S
            10 0 X
            04 0 X
            20 15 S
            11 15 S
            12 15 X
            25 15 X
```

I'd like to create grouped boxplots using time as a factor and treatment as colour. Essentially I need to bind them together and then differentiate between them but not sure how. One way I tried was using:

```
zz<-factor(rep("Z", nrow(z))
bb<-factor(rep("B",nrow(b))
dumB<-merge(z,zz) #this won't work because it says it's too big
dumB<-merge(b,zz)
total<-rbind(dumB,dumZ)
```

But z and zz merge won't work because it says it's 10G in size (which can't be right)

The end plot might be similar to this example: [Boxplot with two levels and multiple data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257019/boxplot-with-two-levels-and-multiple-data-frames)

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

**EDIT: Added boxplot**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach it as follows:

```
# create a list of your data.frames
l <- list(z,b)
# assign names to the dataframes in the list
names(l) <- c("z","b")

# bind the dataframes together with rbindlist from data.table
# the id parameter will create a variable with the names of the dataframes
# you could also use 'bind_rows(l, .id="id")' from 'dplyr' for this
library(data.table)
zb <- rbindlist(l, id="id")

# create the plot
ggplot(zb, aes(x=factor(time), y=Tracer, color=treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~id) +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:

[image]

Other alternatives for creating your plot:

```
# facet by 'time'
ggplot(zb, aes(x=id, y=Tracer, color=treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~time) + 
  theme_bw()

# facet by 'time' & color by 'id' instead of 'treatment'
ggplot(zb, aes(x=treatment, y=Tracer, color=id)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~time) + 
  theme_bw()
```

---

In respons to your last comment: to get everything in one plot, you use `interaction` to distinguish between the different groupings as follows:

```
ggplot(zb, aes(x=treatment, y=Tracer, color=interaction(id, time))) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much indeed! Looks great! Is it possible to facet by time rather than by z/b?

Comment: I just realised that I was actually looking for the boxplots on the same graph, similar to last plot on this page: https://plot.ly/r/box-plots/  where cut is time, price is Tracer and colour=treatment. Is this possible as my graphs just don't look comparable when faceted. :-)

Comment: I really appreciate that thank you, it looks very pretty now. I'll play around with colours I think and widths to make it looks more visible. I've swapped the interaction to id, treatment now :-) thank you so much for your help

Comment: @HCAI Yes, see the update. You have to play a bit with both `width` parameters inside `geom_boxplot` to see what you like the most.

Answer (score 2):

The key is you do not need to perform a `merge`, which is computationally expensive on large tables. Instead assign a new variable and value (source c(b,z) in my code below) to each dataframe and then `rbind`. Then it becomes straight forward, my solution is very similar to @Jaap's just with different faceting.

```
library(ggplot2)
#Create some mock data
t<-seq(1,55,by=2)
z<-data.frame(tracer=sample(t,size = 10,replace = T), time=c(0,15), treatment=c("S","X"))
b<-data.frame(tracer=sample(t,size = 10,replace = T), time=c(0,15), treatment=c("S","X"))
#Add a variable to each table to id itself
b$source<-"b"
z$source<-"z"
#concatenate the tables together
all<-rbind(b,z)

ggplot(all, aes(source, tracer, group=interaction(treatment,source), fill=treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(~time)
```

[image: Barplot Grouped by Time, treatment and DF]

Comment: Thank you for this, it is much appreciated. I chose Jaap's response because I could follow the code without much difficulty and apply it directly to mine without substituting anything. There is also a picture of what I was after so it visually reaffirms that the code works (at least from a novice's point of view)